# Prove that $K = \{ (1); (1 2)(3 4); (1 3)(2 4); (1 4)(2 3) \} \subseteq S_4$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ and $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Considering
$K = \{ (1); (1 2)(3 4); (1 3)(2 4); (1 4)(2 3) \} \subseteq S_4$

a) Prove $K$ is a subgroup of $A_4$ and $S_4$

b) Prove that for every transposition $\tau \in S_4$, $\tau K \tau = K$

**C) Prove that K is a normal subgroup of S4 and A4**

So I have already done a) and b). And for c) the given solution of the exercise states that because $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$, it is enough to verify it for $A_4$. I have verified it for $A_4$ using the result in b).

What I don't get is why they say that  **"because $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$, it is enough to verify it for $A_4$"**? how does normality of $A_4$ imply that $K$ is also normal in $S_4$?. I read somewhere that it is not true that a normal subgroup of a normal subgroup is also normal in the  group, so that couldn't be it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Using the fact that transpositions generate the full symmetric group, b) shows that for every $g\in S_4$, $gKg^{-1} = K$. So $K$ is normal in $S_4$

Comment: It seems to me that the given solution is mistaken. Indeed, if we have a tower of subgroups $K\subseteq H \subseteq G$ with $K$ normal in $H$, and $H$ normal in $G$, it is not necessarily the case that $K$ is normal in $G$. (exercise: find a counterexample)

Comment: Perhaps the given solution meant "... it is enough to verify it for $S_4$"? Indeed, in the situation of my above comment, if $K$ is normal in $G$ then $K$ is normal in $H$.

Comment: Yes you are right, $S\lhd H$ and $H\lhd G$ does not imply $S\lhd G$, but $S\lhd G$ implies $S\lhd H$ for a subgroup $H$, which does not has to be normal in $G$.

Comment: @ Fakemistake Can you prove that last statement?

Comment: @ Brian Shin how to prove that?. I guess it is possible there is a typo on my given solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each $\sigma\in S_4$ can be written as $\sigma=\tau_1\circ\ldots\circ\tau_{n}=:\tau_1\tau_2\ldots\tau_n$ ($\tau_i$ is a transposition for $i=1,\ldots,n$), you have
$$\sigma K\sigma^{-1}=(\tau_1 \ldots \tau_n) K(\tau_1\ldots\tau_n)^{-1}=\tau _1 \ldots\tau_{n-1} \tau_nK\tau_{n}^{-1}\tau_{n-1}^{-1}\ldots\tau_1$$
Now use $\tau_i K\tau_i^{-1}=K$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ to arrive at $\sigma K\sigma^{-1}=K$. Since $\sigma$ is arbitrary, $\sigma K\sigma^{-1}=K$ for all $\sigma \in S_4$

Comment: This is what they did in my provided solutions, the only difference being that they put $A_4$ instead of $S_4$, implying that this should prove K is normal in $A_4$ and by the normality of $A_4$ in $S_4$, K is also normal in A4.

Comment: @Brian Shin what do you think? It seems indeed that there is a typo in my given solution and this reasoning applies as Fakemistake is showing for $S_4$ and then extends for  $A_4 $?

Comment: But what I really was asking is the proof that given since K< A4 < S4 : $ K$ normal in $S4$ implies that $K$ is also normal in $ A4$. I guess it is kind of easy but i am not completely comfortable with it

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You have a condition, which is true for all $\sigma\in S_4$. Since $A_4$ is a subset of $S_4$, the condition is automatically satisfied for all $\sigma\in A_4$. This is it and nothing more!

Answer (score 1):

This is the Klein 4-group. It is normal because conjugation preserves the cycle structure.

Comment: This post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359712/normality-of-a-normal-subgroup-of-normal-subgroup-of-g?rq=1 seems to contradict that.

Comment: What contradicts what? Are you saying this is not the Klein four group?

Comment: No sorry, I was mistaken